# Return does not return Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, samsung-smart-tv

I've two javascript classes (Controller.js & Events.js).
From Events.js i call a XML Parser in Controller.js. The Parser works but does not return anything:

```
SceneEvent.prototype.handleKeyDown = function (keyCode) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case sf.key.ENTER:
            var itemList = null;    
            itemList = Controller.ParseXML("app/data/Event.xml");   
            alert("itemList = " + itemList);
    }
};
```

Controller.js looks like that:

```
Controller.ParseXML = function (url) {
    var itemList = null;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: "xml",
        async: false,
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find("event").each(function() {
                var _id = $(this).attr("id");
                var _eventItemDay = $(this).find("eventItemDay").text();
                ...
                var _eventItemLocation = $(this).find("eventItemLocation").text();

                itemList = {
                    id: _id,
                    eventItemDay: _eventItemDay,
                    eventItemLocation: _eventItemLocation,
                    ...
                    eventItemLocation: _eventItemLocation
                };
            });
            return itemList;
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert("XML ERROR");
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
};
```

When I print out the itemList in Controller.js everything works fine.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using synchronousJAX, but I think you need to put the `return itemList;` at the bottom of your main function, not inside the `success`

Comment: related: [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return the value at the end of the `ParseXML` function, not at the end of the `success` function.

```
Controller.ParseXML = function (url) {
    var itemList = null;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: "xml",
        async: false,
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find("event").each(function() {
                var _id = $(this).attr("id");
                var _eventItemDay = $(this).find("eventItemDay").text();
                ...
                var _eventItemLocation = $(this).find("eventItemLocation").text();

                itemList = {
                    id: _id,
                    eventItemDay: _eventItemDay,
                    eventItemLocation: _eventItemLocation,
                    ...
                    eventItemLocation: _eventItemLocation
                };
            });

        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert("XML ERROR");
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });

    return itemList;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider making your ajax call async and add a callback to your ParseXML function. Something like this in event handler:

```
itemList = Controller.ParseXML("app/data/Event.xml", function(itemList){
    alert("itemList = " + itemList);
});
```

And in ParseXML:

```
Controller.ParseXML = function (url, callback) {
var itemList = null;

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    dataType: "xml",
    async: true,
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find("event").each(function() {
            var _id = $(this).attr("id");
            var _eventItemDay = $(this).find("eventItemDay").text();
            ...
            var _eventItemLocation = $(this).find("eventItemLocation").text();

            itemList = {
                id: _id,
                eventItemDay: _eventItemDay,
                eventItemLocation: _eventItemLocation,
                ...
                eventItemLocation: _eventItemLocation
            };
            callback( itemList );
        });
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert("XML ERROR");
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
        callback( "XML ERROR " + xhr.status + " " + thrownError );
    }
});
```

};

You'll want to check the value in the callback for errors of course.